# Insufficient privileges error on a VisualForce page though I have access (sys Admin profile). Any suggestions?

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Account" recordSetVar="acc">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageblock title="All Account Information">

        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="cancel"/>


    <apex:pageblocktable value="{!acc}" var="a">
        <apex:column >
        <apex:commandLink rerender="ren">{!a.name}
        <apex:param value="{a.ID}" name="aID"/>
        </apex:commandLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!a.type}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!a.industry}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!a.phone}"/>
    </apex:pageblocktable>    

</apex:pageblock>
<apex:panelGrid columns="2">
<apex:commandLink action="{!previous}"> previous </apex:commandLink>
<apex:commandLink action="{!next}"> next </apex:commandLink>
</apex:panelGrid>
<apex:outputPanel id="ren">
    <apex:detail subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.aID}" relatedList="false" />
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Just because you are sys admin does not necessarily mean you have access. Can you confirm you went to `Develop` > `Visualforce Pages` > `MyPage` > `Security` and your profile is under **Enabled Profiles**?

Comment: Yes, I have and the profile is enabled for the page

Comment: Also, your use of a `subject` attribute on your `apex:detail` tag is somewhat perplexing. It should be removed since you are using the id from the `StandardController`.

Comment: Do you have access to the record in question? Insufficient access could also be related to the record, not the page.

Comment: Adrian-This code worked yesterday. I am still learning and this is an example code in a course. What is the alternative that could be used instead?

Comment: @SF99 Just remove the `subject` attribute entirely.

Comment: Sebastian- Yes, I created the record and have access for it.

Comment: Removing the subject attribute now has disabled the link, it does'nt respond

Comment: Never mind, missed the `recordSetVar` piece...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I replicated this and found out the following:

Instead of:

```
<apex:param value="{a.ID}" name="aID"/>
```

You need:

```
<apex:param value="{!a.ID}" name="aID"/>
```

The line of code is missing a '!', which makes the page parameter be '{a.ID}' instead of the actual Id. Then SFDC reports that you don't have privileges for the Account with Id '{a.ID}', which is confusing but makes sense.